# I would like the parent to rotate and translate with the child but scale the parent independently

Tags: transforms, parent

I have parent and child objects.  I want the child to move and rotate with the parent, but I would like to be able to scale the parent without affecting the child in my Python script.  I know that I can set the parent to transform independently with this:
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_skip_children = True
or in the Options menu in the upper right hand corner of the 3d view window.

In my Python code, I would like to be able to detect that a translation in the parent object is occurring, set the parent to transform independently, and then reset that the child transform with the parent. Is that possible?  I am not sure if a modal operator would work, and I do not know what to call the event that would trigger it.

Comment: If your overall goal is to have the child translate and rotate with its parent but scale independently, then one option is to use a `Child Of` constraint instead of parenting. Clear any parent the "child" object may have with `Alt+P`, then add the `Child Of` constraint. Once you assign the "parent", you can then choose which components of its transform are inherited (you can disable all three scale axes).

Comment: This is an answer TTJ

Comment: @TheTrueJard please write this as an answer and not as a comment, so that it can be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: I originally added it as a comment cause it seemed the OP might want a python solution, but after re-reading it I see otherwise. I've added the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your overall goal is to have the child translate and rotate with its parent but scale independently, then one option is to use a `Child Of` constraint instead of parenting. This solution does not require any Python scripting.

1. Clear any parent the "child" object may already have with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Add the `Child Of` constraint. Once you assign the "parent" object, you can choose which components of its transform are inherited. In your specific case, you'll want to disable all three scale axes.

Comment: I had not used constraints before, so this answered my question.  I do need to use Python, and this is what I came up with: constraint=objchild.constraints.new("CHILD_OF"), constraint.target=obparent, constraint.inverse_matrix = objchild.matrix_world.inverted(), constraint.use_scale_x=False, etc. I think it is mostly working.